# Adding a variable to PHP script causes another line to create an error

Tags: php, runtime-error

Quick question...
I'm using this code to communicate with my flash application:

```
<?php
// Only run this script if the sendRequest is from our flash application
if ($_POST['sendRequest'] == "parse") {
// Print the var to flash
print "var1=The user's name is Harry";

}

?>
```

Now this works fine but as soon as I add a variable:

```
<?php
// Only run this script if the sendRequest is from our flash application
if ($_POST['sendRequest'] == "parse") {
$uname = "Name"
// Print the var to flash
print "var1=The user's name is Harry";

}

?>
```

I get an error stating:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PRINT in /home/a4935911/public_html/usersOnline.php on line 7
```

Where line 7 is my print statement. Why is this happening??? Please can someone help. PHP is driving me crazy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP requires that you end lines with a semicolon unless it is the last line. This is because if the semicolon is omitted, it will be evaluated as the same expression as the next line. Change this:

```
$uname = "Name"
```

To this:

```
$uname = "Name";
```

Comment: I think it's obvious that I'm new to PHP. Why is this causing a problem with the print function though? I think that's what confused me the most.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's because the two lines are being evaluated as one.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. I think I'm a bit over my head with PHP. Trying to use it before learning it. Thanks for your help everyone :)

Comment: @user2867893 You're welcome. Added note (from my answer) A semi-colon can be omitted if it's the last line of code with nothing else that will be executed/included thereafter.

Comment: I'm not that interested in PHP at the moment but I just need a bit of it to setup a project I'm working on. You both seem really knowledgable about PHP so do you think either of you could just give me a private hand sorting out some issues I have (I imagine all simple like this) so I don't have to ask too many questions on the forum. Thoughts?

Comment: It is possible to create a chat discussion once the number of comments on a post exceeds a certain amount. However, it is best to ask a different question if the topic is entirely different.

Comment: I don't think that's really that simple. Being completely new to PHP, everything I implement that is said on the forums seems to cause more issues. I don't really want to learn PHP as I don't have the time or need at the moment. I would be eternally grateful to have some help through the chat if that's okay with you.

Comment: Whenever I see an error message in PHP, I usually begin looking at the line _above_ the reported error line. Usually start by looking for that missing semi-colon.

Answer (score 2):

Missing semi-colon in `$uname = "Name"`

change it to `$uname = "Name";`

Rewrite:

```
<?php
// Only run this script if the sendRequest is from our flash application
if ($_POST['sendRequest'] == "parse") {
$uname = "Name";
// Print the var to flash
print "var1=The user's name is Harry";

}

?>
```

**Added note:** A semi-colon can be omitted if it's the last line of code with nothing else that will be executed/included thereafter.

Comment: Exactly. When in doubt about a PHP error, always look at the last statement before the line at which PHP say there is a problem…

Answer (score 0):

write it like this
just add `;` at the end

```
$uname = "Name";
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing a semicollen.

```
$uname = "name";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to end each statement with a semicolon `;`

This error most often means you forgot one of these

```
' ; ' " ) ( [ ]
```

Change

```
$uname = "Name"
```

with

```
$uname = "Name";
```